# Return PHP page based on directory base-name without redirect

Tags: php, redirect, header, pathinfo

I want the server to return a specific PHP page based on the directory name without a redirect. For example:

```
http://www.example.com/home
```

should return the same result as:

```
http://www.example.com/index.php?page=home
```

but it shouldn't redirect the address

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you need to create a special file called '.htaccess' and put it in your web application root directory. File content could be like this:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on

RewriteRule ^/home$ /index.php?page=home [L]
```

Then configure Apache (httpd.conf, httpd-vhosts.conf) to allow your web application to use that .htaccess config file

```
<VirtualHost 127.0.0.1:80>
    DocumentRoot "/path/to/your/webapp"
    ServerName localhost
    <Directory "/path/to/your/webapp">
        AllowOverride All
            Order allow,deny
            Allow from all
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

This is a good read.

http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/misc/rewriteguide.html

Answer (score 1):

PHP can't do this without a redirect, but there are a host of solutions:

Use mod_rewrite with apache (.htaccess)

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^home$ /index.php?page=home
```

Another would be to add an index.php to /home thats only function is to include the document root index.php.

Answer (score 0):

look at frameworks like (my favorites) CodeIngniter or Zend, but you are not limited to it or try to reinvent the wheel by buid your own router

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Apache you can look into htaccess scripts. There are a ton of options available through a google search